# Moving WordPress Content Folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to move WP content folder from default WP content directory.

I followed all instructions on [this Codex section *Moving wp-content folder*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder)

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/public/content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://project.me/public/content' );
```

With this code I've moved the wp-content folder to the desired location but the problem I'm having is that when I try to install any theme, plugin or upload any media file then it asks me for FTP connection information. Look at this screenshot below. After entering credentials it doesn't work, both on local & live web servers.

[image: FTP Credentials prompt]

How can I fix this? Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The new location of the folder does not have proper permissions. You will have to change the permissions of that directory or enter the information that Wordpress is asking you for. A third option could even be to ftp into the server via filezilla, cyberduck, or something like that and upload via one of these tools.

As far as the directory permissions are concerned I can't help you there unless you disclose your server type.

Comment: Wordpress can be a bit finicky especially if you do something like this. I would usually try to avoid any structural changes like what you have done. You can check the options table in the database for anything regarding the file structure.